# Return boolean (true | false) value when all delete operations are successfully performed

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js, graphql

I am using Sequelize, GraphQL and Typescript to write the code. 
I have two tables RecordInformation and OtherDescription. RecordInformation has a foreign key "OtherID" on OtherDescription table.

I have below two code in my resolver file. I am able to delete the records using cascade option in sequelize.

However, I want to know how can I change this code to just return true or false value based on every operation was successfully performed or not. Currently, the return type of map operation is Bluebird< number >[]. I want to return boolean after delete mutation.

```
interface IRecordInformation {
    id: number;
    RecordID: number;
    LabelOptionID: number;
    OtherID: number;
}

interface IListRecordInformation {
    RecordInformationList: IRecordInformation[];
}

deleteRecordInformation(_: null, args: IListRecordInformation) {
  const recordInformationList = args.RecordInformationList;
  return recordInformationList.map((recordInfo) => OtherDescription.destroy({
    where: { id: recordInfo.OtherID }
  }));
},
```

Comment: You can use `.every()`. Does `OtherDescription.destroy({
    where: { id: recordInfo.OtherID }
  })` return a `Boolean`?

Comment: No, it returns a number i.e. count of rowsAffected

Comment: What is the logic which converts boolean to number? Or are you trying to determine when `.map()` is completed?

Comment: I tried to add this code:  deleteRecordInformation(_: null, args: IListRecordInformation) {
          const recordInformationList = args.RecordInformationList;
          return recordInformationList.map((recordInfo) => OtherDescription.destroy({
            where: { id: recordInfo.OtherID }
          })).every(number => number > 0);
        },   But it gives error that operator > can not be applid to Bluebird<number>

Comment: Does `OtherDescription.destroy({ where: { id: recordInfo.OtherID } })` return a `Promise`?

Comment: Yes, it returns Promise<Integer>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to pass `recordInformationList` then use `.every()` with chained `.then()` to check returned `Promise` values

```
Promise.all(
  recordInformationList.map(recordInfo => 
    OtherDescription.destroy({
      where: { id: recordInfo.OtherID }
    })
  )
)
.then(values => values.every(n => n > 0))
.then(bool => bool);
```